# How to sort a select dropdown by string date in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select dropdown which is in dd/MM/yyyy date formate, but it also contains a non-date option. how to dismiss the non-date option when sorting?

sort function:

```
   function str2Date(strD){

    var from = strD.split("/");
    var f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
    return f;
    }


$("#dateSelect  option").sort(function(a, b) {
console.log($(a).val());
   var compA = str2Date($(a).val());
      var compB = str2Date($(b).val());
      return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

The date select:

```
 <select id='dateSelect'>
       <option value="All">All</option>
       <option value="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
       <option value="01/08/2013">01/08/2013</option>
       <option value="01/11/2010">01/11/2010</option>
       <option value="01/12/2014">01/12/2014</option>
       <option value="02/01/2015">02/01/2015</option>
       <option value="02/03/2015">02/03/2015</option>
       <option value="02/06/2016">02/06/2016</option>
       <option value="02/10/2013">02/10/2013</option>
       <option value="02/11/2011">02/11/2011</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: When you pass a String to a date object the date object is null when the browser is not able to create this.

Comment: Exactly, as reporter said. Try to make a date object, and if statement it to remove any option that is not a date.

Comment: i just want to sort the string date part, non-date option should be keep in the top order

Comment: maybe it isn't a task for jquery, I don't say that you can't do it in jquery but you are creating too much logic for something that you can do it easily in other technology

Comment: OK i will use an array to store all non-date part and then insert to it after sorting . But i am still finding an easy way to do this.

Comment: anyway if you insist in do it with javascript you have some library like sugar or datejs for date manipulation 
http://www.datejs.com/
https://code.google.com/archive/p/datejs/wikis/APIDocumentation.wiki
https://sugarjs.com/docs/#/Date

Answer (score 1):

If A is invalid but B is valid, put it before.
If A is valid but B is invalid, put it after.

```js
const options = [
  "01/08/2013",
  "01/11/2010",
  "01/12/2014",
  "All",
  "02/01/2015",
  "02/03/2015",
  "&nbsp;",
  "02/06/2016",
  "02/10/2013",
  "02/11/2011",
];

function str2Date(strD) {
  var from = strD.split("/");
  var f = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
  return f;
}

function isValidDate(str) {
  return !isNaN(Date.parse(str));
}

options.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (!isValidDate(a) && isValidDate(b)) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (isValidDate(a) && !isValidDate(b)) {
    return 1;
  }

  var compA = str2Date(a);
  var compB = str2Date(b);
  return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
});

console.log(options);
```

Comment: a "29/12/2010" will break your function

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

```js
function sortByDate(a, b) {
  if (a.indexOf("/") != -1 || b.indexOf("/") != -1) {
    var adate = a.split("/");
    var bdate = b.split("/");

    if (adate[2] > bdate[2]) {
      return -1;
    } else if (adate[2] < bdate[2]) {

      return 1;
    } else {
      if (adate[1] > bdate[1]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (adate[1] < bdate[1]) {
        return 1;
      } else {

        if (adate[0] > bdate[0]) {
          return -1;
        } else if (adate[0] < bdate[0]) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }

      }
    }
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
}


var itemsId = document.getElementById("dateSelect");
var items = itemsId.getElementsByTagName("option");
var arrall = [];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

  arrall.push(items[i].value);
}

var lastone = arrall.sort(sortByDate);
while (itemsId.firstChild) {
  itemsId.firstChild.remove();
}
for (var i = 0; i < lastone.length; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.innerHTML = lastone[i];
  opt.value = lastone[i];
  itemsId.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select id='dateSelect'>
       <option value="All">All</option>
       <option value="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
       <option value="01/08/2013">01/08/2013</option>
       <option value="01/11/2010">01/11/2010</option>
       <option value="01/12/2014">01/12/2014</option>
       <option value="02/01/2015">02/01/2015</option>
       <option value="02/03/2015">02/03/2015</option>
       <option value="02/06/2016">02/06/2016</option>
       <option value="02/10/2013">02/10/2013</option>
       <option value="02/11/2011">02/11/2011</option>          
    </select>
```